# Not able to implement cardview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

This is my UserAdapter class

```
 public class UserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserCardHolder> {

    private Activity adapterActivity;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    protected List<UserCardData> userCardDataList = new ArrayList<>();

    public UserAdapter(Activity activity,List<UserCardData> userCardDataList){
        this.adapterActivity= activity;
        this.userCardDataList = userCardDataList;
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) adapterActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getItemCount() {
        return userCardDataList.size();
    }

    public UserCardData removeItem(int position) {
        final UserCardData model = userCardDataList.remove(position);
        notifyItemInserted(position);
        return model;
    }

    public void addItem(int position, UserCardData model) {
        userCardDataList.add(position, model);
        notifyItemInserted(position);
    }

    public void moveItem(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
        final UserCardData model = userCardDataList.remove(fromPosition);
        userCardDataList.add(toPosition, model);
        notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
    }
    public void animateTo(List<UserCardData> models) {
        applyAndAnimateRemovals(models);
        applyAndAnimateAdditions(models);
        applyAndAnimateMovedItems(models);
    }

    private void applyAndAnimateRemovals(List<UserCardData> newModels) {
        for (int i = userCardDataList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            final UserCardData model = userCardDataList.get(i);
            if (!newModels.contains(model)) {
                removeItem(i);
            }
        }
    }

    private void applyAndAnimateAdditions(List<UserCardData> newModels) {
        for (int i = 0, count = newModels.size(); i < count; i++) {
            final UserCardData model = newModels.get(i);
            if (!userCardDataList.contains(model)) {
                addItem(i, model);
            }
        }
    }

    private void applyAndAnimateMovedItems(List<UserCardData> newModels) {
        for (int toPosition = newModels.size() - 1; toPosition >= 0; toPosition--) {
            final UserCardData model = newModels.get(toPosition);
            final int fromPosition = userCardDataList.indexOf(model);
            if (fromPosition >= 0 && fromPosition != toPosition) {
                moveItem(fromPosition, toPosition);
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public UserCardHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_card_services, parent, false);
        final UserCardHolder userCardHolder = new UserCardHolder(view);
        userCardHolder.itemView.setTag(userCardHolder);

        return userCardHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(UserCardHolder userCardHolder, int position) {
        UserCardData userCardData = userCardDataList.get(position);
        Log.e("hello", "in bind view holder");
        Log.e(" hello", userCardData.uname);
        userCardHolder.txtuname.setText(userCardData.uname);
        userCardHolder.txtphoneno.setText(userCardData.phoneno);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This is my UserCardView class

```
    public class UserCardView extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private UserAdapter userAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    private List<UserCardData> userCardDataList = new ArrayList<>();

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutInflater,ViewGroup viewGroup,Bundle onsavedinstance){
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview,viewGroup,false);

        databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper.getDbInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        userCardDataList = databaseHelper.getUserData();
        userAdapter = new UserAdapter(getActivity(),userCardDataList) ;
        recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);
        //userAdapter.animateTo(userCardDataList);
        return view;

    }
}
```

This is CardHolder class

```
 public class UserCardHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView txtuname,txtphoneno;
    public UserCardHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        txtuname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_username);
        txtphoneno = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_phoneno);
    }
}
```

When I run an application I got this exception.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: com.example.mithilamin.servicestation1, PID: 7619
                                                                                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                                      at com.example.mithilamin.servicestation1.usercard.UserAdapter.onBindViewHolder(UserAdapter.java:93)
                                                                                      at com.example.mithilamin.servicestation1.usercard.UserAdapter.onBindViewHolder(UserAdapter.java:14)
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5217)
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5250)
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4487)
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4363)
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1961)
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1370)
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1333)
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:562)
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2900)
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3071)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15614)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15614)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15614)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1043)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15614)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15614)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15614)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15614)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15614)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15614)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2102)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1859)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1077)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5884)
                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Ha
```

Comment: It is time for debugging. Did you tried debugging? Please edit your question!

Comment: `void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)` on a null object reference. check using breakpoint before settext. the textview/the reference should be null

Comment: Your Android error log is heavily indented to the right - would you edit it so that it is readable without scrolling please, to assist future readers? Please also refrain from asking for urgency here - volunteers answer questions at leisure here, and do not take well to being hurried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your error is very clear, error is with this line

```
userCardHolder.txtuname.setText(userCardData.uname);
```

check in `layout_card_services.xml` whether you have `text_username` named TextView

Answer (score 3):

Your issue clearly telling **NullPointerException**:

**Edit 2:**

```
userCardHolder.txtuname is null.
```

Can you please replace code same as below:

```
((UserCardHolder) holder).txtuname.setText(userCardData.uname);
((UserCardHolder) holder).txtphoneno.setText(userCardData.phoneno);
```

Make sure that you do not have null variable for TextView, because you are using this variable to set text.

Hope this will make sense.

Comment: @hardipatel, Log.e(" hello", userCardData.uname); , are you getting log for it ?

Comment: @hardipatel, Can you please try my Edit 2: ?

Comment: @hardipatel, try Edit 2 for now.